# MySQL query works fine, but gives error when implemented in java code in Netbeans

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql that insert in multiple tables fields based in the last generated primary key of one of the tables;

```
INSERT INTO rentals(Customer_idCustomer,RentedDate) VALUES (1,curdate()); 
SET @last_id_in_rentals = LAST_INSERT_ID();
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO rental_movie (Movie_idMovie,Rentals_idRentals) VALUES (1,@last_id_in_rentals);
INSERT INTO transaction(idRentals,DaysRented,Cost,TotalCost) VALUES(@last_id_in_rentals,2,2,4);
COMMIT;
```

Works fine in MySQL, but when I implement that same query in Netbeans it gaves me this error:

```
"com.mysql.jdbc.excceptions.jdbc4.MysqlSyntaxErrorException:You have
an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'SET @last_id_in_rentals=LAST_INSERT_ID();
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO rental_movie(Mo'at line2"
```

This is my whole connection:

```
ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        Statement stmt= null;
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";
        String userid = "xxx";
        String password = "";
    /**
     * Creates new form NewRental
     */
    public NewRental() {
        initComponents();
    }
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        try{
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userid, password);
            String sql="SELECT idCustomer FROM customer\n" +
            " WHERE idCustomer =?;";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            pst.setString(1,jTextField2.getText());
            String idcustomer;
             String idmovie;
            idcustomer=jTextField2.getText();
            idmovie=rental_movie.getText();

           rs=pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){

                  try{
               asterisco1.setText("");
        sql="SELECT idMovie FROM movie\n" +
            " WHERE idMovie =?;";

            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            pst.setString(1,rental_movie.getText());

            rs=pst.executeQuery();
                  if(rs.next()){
                      asterisco2.setText("");
                      mandatory.setText("");
            sql="INSERT INTO rentals(Customer_idCustomer,RentedDate) VALUES (1,curdate()); \n" +
"SET @last_id_in_rentals = LAST_INSERT_ID();\n" +
"\n" +
"INSERT INTO rental_movie (Movie_idMovie,Rentals_idRentals) VALUES (1,@last_id_in_rentals);\n" +
"INSERT INTO transaction(idRentals,DaysRented,Cost,TotalCost) VALUES(@last_id_in_rentals,2,2,4);\n" +
"COMMIT;";
                                    //Se crea un id de Rentas automatico.
            stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
//            sql="UPDATE rental_movie \n" +
//"INNER JOIN rentals  ON rental_movie.Rentals_idRentals = rentals.idRentals\n" +
//"SET Movie_idMovie ="+idmovie+";\n"; 
//            stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
//            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
//            

//            sql="INSERT INTO rental_movie(Movie_idMovie,Rentals_idRentals)\n" +
//                       "VALUES ("+idmovie+","+idcustomer+");";
//            stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
//            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
//            sql="INSERT INTO transaction(idRentals)\n" +
//"SELECT idRentals FROM rentals\n" +
//"WHERE rentals.Customer_idCustomer="+idcustomer+";";
//            stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
//            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
//            sql="update transaction\n" +
//"  set idRentals = (\n" +
//"               select rentals.idRentals \n" +
//"                 from rentals\n" +
//"                where rentals.idRentals = transaction.idRentals\n" +
//"              ),\n" +
//"DaysRented = ,\n" +
//"Cost=,\n" +
//"TotalCost=\n" +
//" where exists (\n" +
//"               select * \n" +
//"                 from rentals \n" +
//"                where rentals.idRentals = transaction.idRentals\n" +
//"              );";


                  }

                  else{
                      asterisco2.setForeground (Color.red);
                      asterisco2.setText("*");
                      mandatory.setForeground (Color.red);
                      mandatory.setText("Mandatory Field.");
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record could not be found. ", "Movie don't exist.", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                  }}
                 catch(Exception e){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
                 }


//               
            }
            else{
                asterisco1.setForeground (Color.red);
                asterisco1.setText("*");
                mandatory.setForeground (Color.red);
                mandatory.setText("Mandatory Field.");
                             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record could not be found. ", "Client don't exist.", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);     

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }


    }
```

Comment: It looks like your connection doesn't allow multiple queries, can you post your connection(but be sure to XXX out any usernames, passwords and hosts, we don't need to know that information)?

Comment: already put the connection if so how can I manipulate the query so it can be accepted in Netbeans? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `?allowMultiQueries=true` to the end of your connection string: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?allowMultiQueries=true`

Comment: post it as an answer so I can accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
?allowMultiQueries=true
```

to the end of your connection string so it looks like:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?allowMultiQueries=true
```